# Paypal Returns Auth code only after Subscription completed?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to set up a subscription payment for Paypal. I am testing with the sandbox with the following code.

```xml
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
   <br/>
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"><br/>
   <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="3PFTX58KDNXHQ"><br/>
   <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"><br/> 
   <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"><br/>
</form>
```

Above code is a auto generated subxcription button code from my sandbox account.

It is working file with subscription in sandbox. I mean after the subscription complete it is showing right data in my sandbox account with the subscription information. But the problem is when the subscription is done and user got back to site is having a auth get parameter with it. like

`http://my-site.com/this-subscribe-button-return-url.php?auth=[auth_code_from_paypal]&form_charset=UTF-8`

Actually My return url is like the following
http://my-site.com/this-subscribe-button-return-url.php?status=success

I have my ipn enabled and its pointing to different url than return url.

**What is this auth value? and what am I supposed to do with it?**

I want the whole subscription data posted back when somebody completes his subscription process to a certain url (like notify_url). I have already set my notify_url in my ipn settings.

Please somebody give a proper solution to these problems. Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this hope this would help u  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641421/paypal-return-url?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

How are you wanting to get the information back, or what method are you trying to use?  If you wanting to get the information back and validate it, you want to use [PDT](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer).  This will allow you to validate the information that is being sent over to you as well.

Comment: Actually I am not handling a direct payment. I am working with subscription. In the sandbox site you can create a subscription button with the success url, cancel url etc. I put my success url there as I mentioned in my problem. But It is not working in the way I expected.

Comment: No data will be returned to your return URL because you are setting up a free trial.  If you are wanting to get data returned to your return URL via PDT, you wouldn't be able to offer a free trial.